# Is it better to reference ID or tag type in css for a tag only appearing once?

Tags: css

Lets say I have only one `<a>` tag in a header in my html. Would it be better to give that link an ID and then reference it as `#ID {}` or just write `header a {}`

I suppose it's not very significant either way but I'm curious whether something is standard.

Code ex:

```
<header>
  <a>Link </a>
</header>
```

where the document has no other a tag inside a header tag and css references the only one with header `a {}`

versus 
    
      Link

where the document still has no other a tag inside a header tag but CSS references the only one with `#referenced {}`

Comment: Please provide a sample code, or better, one for each scenarii to compare.

Comment: The question is, are you likely in the future to add additional `a` elements inside the `header`, and if so, do you want the standard styling to apply to those elements as well? In such cases, I see no problem with the `header a` approach.

Comment: And there are more ways to refer to one singular element. `a:first-child` springs to mind. Just do what comes natural.

Comment: Wait a minute, I wasn't thinking. The answer is to use a class of course. Never give an element an ID for the sole purpose of referencing it in a stylesheet.